# Is there any benefit to to define constant local variables as static ( c++)?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
void Animation::playAnimation() const
{
    static const int index = 0;
    const std::string& animationFileName = 
    m_animationContainer.getAnimationName(index);
    static const int zOrder = -1;
    static bool isLooping = false;

    AnimationBank::play(animationFileName,
                        zOrder,
                        isLooping);
}
```

Is there any benefit to to define constant local variables as `static`? Or it is unnecessary and even bad practice.

Comment: see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: ...also, please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431574/what-are-pros-and-cons-to-define-constant-local-variables-as-static-c "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Beyond @Christophe's very good answer, the code generated for the static is most likely worse than the one for the local variable, so if you're interested the under-the-hood benefit, statics are worse on modern processors.

The reason is that the statics must be located somewhere in memory that can be found by all the other threads and by all the other invocations.  This basically means putting them in global memory.

Over the years, processors & compilers together have significantly optimized access to local variables due to the popularity of their usage, as compared with other variables, such as globals, statics, and fields.  The compiler may choose to store a local variable in a CPU register, and even if it doesn't (so it uses the invocation stack instead) all of the stack is almost certainly in the cache.   Accessing the stack is usually a short displacement addressing mode (off the stack pointer register).  However, accessing globals or statics usually requires and extended offset or absolute address, so the resulting instructions doing so are longer than their equivalent for stack memory access.

All that being said, due to the combination of static and const the compiler may detect that it can substitute the constant value at the point of usage, so perhaps use of const mitigates the above.  Still, your snippet shows at least one non-const statics, so perhaps the discussion is topical.

Comment: Are you sure static **constants** have to be put into memory?

Answer (score 8):

It is not a question of benefits, but a question of semantics:

- A static variable in a function (even a member function), means that the variable is shared between all the calls of that function. So one call of that function has a side effect on the subsequent calls.
- A non static variable is unique to each execution of the function.

So, unless it is required for some specific and well justified reason, keep  local variables non static.

***Additional remark:*** The static variable is also shared accross different threads.  So calling this function from more than one thread at a time might result in race conditions and UB (even if called for different objects).

Comment: Starting from C++11, the standard defines const static variables thread safe. Non-const, static variables on the other hand, are not.

Comment: This is about constants. They can't change their value, so there is no meaningful semantical difference between constants that are shared between multiple function calls and local ones.

Comment: The only difference is if the initialization has side effects.

Comment: @MikeMB Indeed, my answer was general.  If it's a `const`, the optimizer will propagate it anyway, whether it's `static` or not. But there's still a subtle difference: as you pointed out, the object initializer could use some side effets, so that choosing static or not could distort the expected behavior.  For all these reasons, I'd still strongly suggest to use `static` if and only if the `const` is really something that is intrinsically linked to the class.  Show the intent in the code and let the optimizer do its job.

Comment: So semantically, it doesn't make a difference if the variable is a constant and its address is not taken. The rest of the question is: which one should you use?

Comment: @user253751 If the purpose is to give a name to a constant, use a local const: the constant propagation will generate optimized code using the fixed value. If you want an object but prevent that the value is accidentally overwritten, use local or static as you would do if the variable would not be const. Be consistent with the semantic you want, and not with some arbitrary rule that is supposed to help optimization. “premature optimization is the root of all evil”

Answer (score 2):

A local variable is initialized or constructed every time the function is called. Local variables are stored on the stack and therefore are generally thread safe.

A static local variable is initialized or constructed only once; the first time the function is called. Local static variables are not stored on the stack and therefore are generally not thread safe.

A const local variable is a variable that does not change and is initialized or constructed every time the function is called. Local const variables are stored on the stack and therefore are generally thread safe.

A static const local variable is a variable that does not change and is initialized or constructed only once; the first time the function is called. Local static const variables are not stored on the stack and therefore are generally not thread safe.

Compilers may be able to optimize const variables into a compile time constant.

Compilers may be able to optimize non-static variables by by keeping them in registers rather than on the stack.

Comment: Why would local `static const` variables not be thread safe? Their value is constant even if their value is located on the hep.

Comment: @unifiedmodelingsandwich: What if two threads make the first call to the function at the same time? Then both threads would try to initialize that `static const` variable.

Comment: Not in C++11 they wouldn't. Dynamic initialization of function-local statics is thread-safe.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau [Since C++11, static local variable initialisation is thread-safe](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables). The A is still correct in saying that it is not _in general_ thread safe, but it would be more accurate to say that this is only the case prior to C++11.

Comment: @unifiedmodelingsandwich: Thanks for the info. I am mostly stuck on C++03 :-(

Comment: I say "generally thread safe" because multi-threading is too large a topic to cover here. There are object specific threading issues even with local static const variables that can occur during construction and run time calls to the object's methods. Constructors instantiate other objects, can call other methods, call into the operating system, and libraries. Same is true of calls to const object methods. Even calls to static methods of the same object could be unsafe.  Compilers cannot detect all of these issues when compiling one source file.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau, under what circumstances could multiple threads writing the same value to a variable be a problem - the variable will never be in a undefined state because no matter which thread executes first the other thread will be overwriting the variable with the same value.  This would not be true if it was only static.  Only mutable variables can be unsafe (which is one of the arguments for functional programming).

Comment: @Trevor, if that variable has a non-trivial constructor, then the initialisation is more than just writing some constant values to some memory locations.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau, excellent point.  A non-trivial type could certainly mutate some other state during construction.  I was too blinkered on the specific cases in the OP's example.